# Использование QModelIndex в модели

Tags: c++, qt5

В QAbstractModel для доступа к элементам используются объекты типа QModelIndex, которые создаются исходя из строки и столбца, переданных в качестве аргументов. Понятное дело, что проще (и быстрее всего) такая модель будет работать с вектором (за счет произвольного доступа к элементам) и медленнее с контейнерами, которые его не имеют. Меня же интересует создание модели, работающей с map, в которой в качестве ключей, для простоты, используются int. Тогда ключи мы сможем использовать в качестве row. Но возник вопрос: а как модель взаимодействует со view? Всмысле, например, модель предоставляет доступ к 10 элементам в контейнере, но, к примеру в ней нет элемента в row 3, зато есть элемент в row 10 (нумерация от ноля), а на row 3 она возвращает невалидный индекс. Вью отобразит только 9 элементов (с 0 по 9, при этом 3 будет пустым), или отобразит все 10 элементов?

Также меня интересует поведение QPresistantModelIndex после удаления строки в модели. Если это была строка, в который находились данные, на которые указывал постоянный индекс, то он станет не валидным? А если это была другая строка, но после ее удаления данные, на которые указывает постоянный индекс, теперь находятся в другой строке, то на какие данные он будет указывать после этого?

Comment: Количество строк для отображения указываются в методе rowCount и это ваше решение что и как учитывать (валидные, не валидные, удалённые и так далее). Этот метод, а также data() и остальные в модели работают в комплексе друг с другом. В доках есть пример

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вы наверно непоняли: у меня 10 элементов, и я возвращаю rowCount 10. Но у меня нет row под номером 3 (будет возвращен пустой индекс), зато есть row под номером 10.

Comment: Я понял правильно. Значит отображается 10 элементов и выводится 10, но не по индексу, а по id, или ещё как-то, а именно так как вы решите. В том и смысл, что вам нужно решить что и как вы будете отображать, соответственно в классе модели вы свое решение и реализуете.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin так я уже ришил! Ну я же пишу: "пустой индекс" и что индекс с row 10 возвратит валидное значение. Вопрос же не в том как это сделать, а что отобразится во вью!

Comment: Во view отобразится то, что вы вернёте из data(). Сделайте какую-нибудь реализацию поговорим конкретнее

Comment: @AlexanderChernin у меня тогда встречный вопрос: когда у меня будет реализация, то зачем мне спрашивать?

Comment: Вот и я думаю, что когда вы решите, что  и как отображается вы сразу поймёте как сделать реализацию. Конечно, мне не сложно сделать за вас, но мне трудно написать ответ потому что у меня планшет, а до компа далековато. Каникулы :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я не пойму, вы читать не умеете или издеваетесь? Мне не нужно решать, что и как отображаться должно, я хочу знать что отбразится во вью, используещем модель. Вы понимаете разницу?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87886/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-andrej-levkovitch).